# Determine a JavaFX table row details when reusing tableview context menu

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a requirement similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770391/context-menu-only-showing-for-a-few-tableview-rows-javafx-fxml) example.

In the EventHandler callback, how do I determine which row was clicked on?

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
  // how do I get the row details when reusing context menu and handler code?
}
```

I am sharing the context menu because I have to add a CheckMenuItem who's state is "global" to the table, i.e. if its selected on any row, I want to show it as checked when I click on any other row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a row factory and one context menu per row, as in the question you linked.

For the "global" `CheckMenuItem`, create a `BooleanProperty` and bidirectionally bind the `CheckMenuItem`s' selected properties to it.

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithContextMenu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::valueProperty));

        BooleanProperty globalSelection = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        table.setRowFactory(t -> {
            TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Do something");
            item1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Do something with "+row.getItem().getName()));
            MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Do something else");
            item2.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Do something else with "+row.getItem().getName()));

            CheckMenuItem item3 = new CheckMenuItem("Global selection");
            item3.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(globalSelection);

            contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2, new SeparatorMenuItem(), item3);
            row.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isEmpty) -> {
                if (isEmpty) {
                    row.setContextMenu(null);
                } else {
                    row.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                }
            });
            return row ;
        });

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 25).mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i, i)).forEach(table.getItems()::add);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```