# Lookup model details when constructing JavaFX context menuitem

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490470/determine-a-javafx-table-row-details-when-reusing-tableview-context-menu) question.

I need to construct one of the MenuItems with some content from the row model.

row.getItem() is null as the row isnt initialized in the rowfactory callback.

Is there a way to defer the creation of the context menu when the row model has been populated?

For example, if the row as a String property name = "foo", the MenuItem should display "Add foo".

Comment: Just add a listener to the row's `itemProperty` and update the menu item when it changes.

Comment: Any chance you can point me to an example? Do I create the context menu after the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of my answer to  [Determine a JavaFX table row details when reusing tableview context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490470/determine-a-javafx-table-row-details-when-reusing-tableview-context-menu) you would do

```
table.setRowFactory(t -> {
    TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();

    // ...

    row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        item1.setText(/* value depending on newItem... */);
    });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!